# Order by field A, and stopping only when field A changes after a certain limit

Tags: sql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a table of users, and one field on the table is company.

I'm processing a certain number of users each days, so I use limit(x). I sort them by company and want to make sure my limit ends when a company change. I don't want to have users from one company processed and other not. But I want to process a minimum number of users per day, not a number of companies.

e.g if I have 3 users from company A, 2 users from company B, 3 from company C and have a limit of 4 (minimum to process)

It will currently split here

AAAB][BCCC -> not good (I have 1 user from B processed and another one not processed)

I want to have all users from company A + ALL users from company B.

AAABB][CCC -> good

I just want to use limit as a minimum number of user to process in this case.

I currently have User.order(lower('company')).limit(4 + 10) and loop through each to stop when company change after my real limit (4) has been reached but this won't work if there are companies with more than 10 users. Plus it's just a very poor solution.

What's the best way to do that (ideally in 1 simple SQL statement)? Bonus point for ActiveRecord syntax

Worth noting I have 10'000s of rows in my database.

Comment: what type of sql you use? (PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.)

Comment: Did not have time to solve it, I'm working with ActiveRecord and need to search how rank works first (like the idea, not sure about performance ranking on string, I have a lot of records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rank(Window function) over company within subquery.

1. Find the rank of 4th row (subquery).
2. Select rows with rank less or equal to rank of 4th row (main query).

   select * from
   (
   select *, DENSE_RANK() over(order by company) as kr 
   from users 
   ) tab
   where kr <=
   (
   select DENSE_RANK() over(order by company) as kr from users LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
   )

might be optimized